# Google sheets - Conditional formating between 2 dates in function of real time

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-dates, google-sheets-timestamp

Is it possible to make a cell automatically highlighted during a time interval relative to the instant T, in real time.
The cell should only be highlighted when the time comes and it becomes transparent again after the time has elapsed...

I want cell B3 to be automaticaly highlited with the green color AND filled with the matching value (Task 1 to Task 12) accordingly to the interval of time compared to the moment.

**Below is what I want to obtain:**

[image]

**But unfortunatly, here is what I got: B3 is still empty and trapsarent**

[image]

**Here is the Sheet2 content:**

[image]

**I made this conditional formating:**

[image]

Here's my file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WXwT3RkM_v__zx5VTFX8ww8kmTQo2Mjx08BRLfhQcRg/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

In columns `A` and `B` of `Sheet2` no dates have been inserted but only text with the appearance of a date.
The proof is that their format is different from that of `Sheet1!B1`.
Then you just have to swap their month and day, in accordance with that of `now()`.
I am attaching [your file edited](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uqwyq_mUD-qxSHb90qr2-YLfT2cdNpCJtdRPnmBwyyY/edit?usp=sharing) with also the correct conditional formatting to apply, which will leave cell `Sheet1!B3` white only in the absence of TASK.
`Sheet1!B3` contains this formula:

```
=index(ifna(query(unique(IF((now()>=Sheet2!A2:A13)*(B1<=Sheet2!B2:B13),Sheet2!C2:C13,),"",1))))
```

`P.S.`: *in File `->` Settings `->` Calculation you will have to set the recalculation at each modification and every minute.*

Comment: Thanks @Daniele, the conditional formating you made is for not empty cell but in fact I wanted to highlight different cell ranges in Sheet1 "Form 1 for 1 cell B3 for example, Form 2 for 2 cells B3 and C3, Form 3 for 3 cells B3, C3 and D3... etc) for each task... is it possible? you can see your own file

Comment: could you do on my file some practical examples of how you would make the requests and what you would like to achieve?

Comment: I updated your file by adding 3 columns in Sheet2 (Length, Width and Driver), the goal is obtaining when it's time between the 2 intervals ETA and ETD a conditional formatting covering a shape based on the number of cells (length) x cells (width) AND another complication: the conditional formating has to be green if Driver is John Doe and red if it's Jane Doe